# Server differences in mobilefirst

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

Hello all i know it is not a place to discuss theories. But i need to know what is the difference between mobilefirst server that is built locally While using developer edition through eclipse and IBM mobilefirst server that's for purchase. what are the limitations for free version of server provided and can i deploy the free version server on some other system.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?  Knowing that would make it easier to give a complete answer to your question.  In addition the technical difference that Idan mentioned in his answer, there is also a licensing difference - the license for Developer Edition doesn't permit it to be used in production, only for development.  That may not matter for your question, depending on the reason why you are asking...

Answer (score 1):

The Authenticity feature is not available in the developer edition. That is the only difference.